# Outlook auto-archive

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, outlook-addin, autoarchive

will the folder structure in my inbox be kept when I do an auto-archive of my inbox or will all emails be moved to one folder? If not how is it possible to achieve this? 
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook AutoArchive retains your folder structure intact in the Archive PST file.